# Getting MultiLangDaemon Exception

Tags: java, aws-sdk, daemon

I implemented a kinesis stream consumer client using node wrapper and getting this MultiLangDaemon execution error as shown below.

`Starting MultiLangDaemon ... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant software.amazon.kinesis.common.InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238) at software.amazon.kinesis.common.InitialPositionInStream.valueOf(InitialPositionInStream.java:21) at software.amazon.kinesis.multilang.config.MultiLangDaemonConfiguration$2.convert(MultiLangDaemonConfiguration.java:208) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:491) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1007) at software.amazon.kinesis.multilang.config.KinesisClientLibConfigurator.lambda$getConfiguration$0(KinesisClientLibConfigurator.java:65) at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.forEach(Collections.java:2064) at software.amazon.kinesis.multilang.config.KinesisClientLibConfigurator.getConfiguration(KinesisClientLibConfigurator.java:63) at software.amazon.kinesis.multilang.MultiLangDaemonConfig.<init>(MultiLangDaemonConfig.java:101) at software.amazon.kinesis.multilang.MultiLangDaemonConfig.<init>(MultiLangDaemonConfig.java:74) at software.amazon.kinesis.multilang.MultiLangDaemonConfig.<init>(MultiLangDaemonConfig.java:58) at software.amazon.kinesis.multilang.MultiLangDaemon.buildMultiLangDaemonConfig(MultiLangDaemon.java:171) at software.amazon.kinesis.multilang.MultiLangDaemon.main(MultiLangDaemon.java:220) No enum constant software.amazon.kinesis.common.InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON`

I already cross checked properties file with details shown below listed there
initialPositionInStream, processingLanguage,streamName,executableName etc.

TRIM_HORIZON is set as value for initialPositionInStream Not sure why software.amazon.kinesis.common.InitialPositionInStream this object missing this value?

I am using node consumer client as mentioned here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-implementation-app-nodejs.html

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Code samples are included in aws docs link I shared above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to help community by answering this specific error fix. It was .properties file update for that respective parameter key name. Although I am getting couple of other java.lang.RuntimeException that will try to resolve and ask for resolution in separate threads.

Comment: Watch this thread for error resolution provided for this issue https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/issues/633